# Why NetSuite does not create Payment Files?

Tags: netsuite, erp, banking

NetSuite does not create payment files after the installation of the Electronic Bank Payment bundle. All files stay in the database as Queued.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD5lQ.jpg)

Comment: Where did you expect the payment files to appear?

Comment: In the File Cabinet, folder Payment files/.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of SuiteAnswers that explain why this might be the case [26150](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26150/), [93269](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/93269/), [63278](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/63278/), [83929](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/83929/), [83540](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/83540/), [79178](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/79178/), [74428](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/74428/), [33448](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/33448/). Take a look and follow the advice, as the  question doesn't contain enough information to answer it accurately.